# Removal of a BST node: a trifecta of failures

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

Just as a heads up, I wanted to submit this code 2 years ago, but wanted to try and revisit it periodically to see if I could fix it. I understand the logic, but there has to be something awry with my pointers. I ultimately made three separate attempts. None work. The bulk of the code was written by the professor, and the other functions I implemented are fine. Unfortunately he didn't give me any pointers (pun intended) on how to do the removal. It's the same story each time: some kind of mess with a pointer and a read access violation. Here's one of my three attempts:

```
template <typename K, typename T>
void BST<K, T>::remove(const K& k)
 Attempt 1
     If p is a nullptr, return. 
    if (p == nullptr)
        return;
    // If the key is greater than the p's key, go down the right subtree
    if (k > p->key)
        remove(p->right, k);
    // If it's less, then it's in the left subtree
    else if (k < p->key)
        remove(p->left, k);
    // If key is found
    else if (p->key == k) {
        // And it has both children
        if (p->left && p->right) {
            Node *q = findMin(p->right);
            p->key = q->key;
            p->data = q->data;
            remove(p->right, k);
        }
        else if (p->right) {
            // Copy right child to p and delete p
            p->key = p->right->key;
            p->data = p->right->data;
            p->parent->right = p->right;
            p->right->parent = p->parent;
            delete p;
            p = nullptr;
        }
        // If it only has left child
        else if (p->left) {
            // Copy left child to p and delete p
            p->key = p->left->key;
            p->data = p->left->data;
            p->parent->left = p->left;
            p->left->parent = p->parent;
            delete p;
            p = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            if (p->parent->left = p)
                p->parent->left = nullptr;
            else
                p->parent->right = nullptr;
            delete p;
        }
    }
```

It gets called by this function, which was coded by my professor:

```
template <typename K, typename T>
void BST<K, T>::remove(const K& k) {
    if (root && root->key == k) {
        Node*p = root;
        if (root->left&&root->right) {
            Node*q = findMin(root->right);
            root->key = q->key;
            root->data = q->data;
            remove(root->right, k);
        }
        else {
            if (root->left)
                root = root->left;
            else if (root->right)
                root = root->right;
            else
                root = nullptr;
            delete p;
        }
    }
    else
        remove(root, k);
}
```

Comment: *Unfortunately he didn't give me any pointers (pun intended) on how to do the removal.* -- Draw the removal on paper.  Write down the steps on what needs to be done to remove a node.  Translate what you have on paper into code.  When the program fails, use the debugger to see where the program goes against what you drew on paper.

Comment: Is [the BST wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) any help?

Comment: You should be able to figure out the logical flaw by making a simple observation: in the case of "`(p->left && p->right)`" the action taken is obviously to find an appropriate value to replace the `k` value in the current node, which has just been found. Then the shown code recursively continues to search for the `k` value starting from the ***right*** child. But didn't you just find the `k` value? In the ***current*** node? Why is this still searching for the `k` value in the right node? You just proved that `p->key == k`. Searching for `k` in `right`, as Mr. Spock would say, is illogical.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Right, my original attempt was using a recursive call for the key that replaced the deleted node's key. So for example if this was called to delete a node with the value "78" and the value of q is "80", then p's key would become 80 and the function would get called with the parent node of the right subtree and the value of 80, correct? Though I still get the same read access violation.

Comment: This was the only thing that was obviously wrong to me. Without a [mre], very little else can be said about this. The read access violation could be because of a bug anywhere else in the entire code, and not just this part.

Comment: I'll try and reproduce it without any of the fluff. 

@PaulMcKenzie On paper it certainly seems to make sense. My primary issue seems to revolve around memory allocation and pointers. Dangling pointers, memory leaks, buffer overflow, etc. I'm hitting against the walls of my understanding. Conscious incompetence. Stage two.

Comment: A memory access violation indicates *something*'s wrong with your use of pointers, somewhere. Where does the error occur? Which pointer is invalid? Once you know that, the next step is to figure out where the invalid value came from, and why.

Comment: @NobodyNada-ReinstateMonica That's what I'm attempting to find now. I'm trying to trace the debugger. I did see that I had an error in my deletion when it came to the (p->left) and (p->right) statements. Implicit in the logic is that I'd be deleting a leaf node. That's not necessarily true. It could be that the right or left child of p is a root of a sub-tree. I'm trying to force the deletion of a leaf node, moving the key that we want to get rid of down the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it handled. My issues were numerous:

1) `remove(root->right, k);`

As was mentioned in the above comments, k was overwritten by the new key and no longer exists in the tree. I had made changes to this line before, but it wasn't the only problem I had.

2) `p->parent->right = p->right;
   p->right->parent = p->parent;`

The node *has* a right child, it isn't necessarily a right child *itself*. Likewise with the left child statements.

3) `delete p;
   p = nullptr;`

Implicit in these statements is the fact that since it only has one child, that that child is a leaf. It could very well be a parent node of a subtree.

Corrected code:

```
    // If p is a nullptr, return. 
    if (p == nullptr)
        return;
    // If the key is greater than the p's key, go down the right subtree
    else if (k > p->key)
        remove(p->right, k);
    // If it's less, then it's in the left subtree
    else if (k < p->key)
        remove(p->left, k);
    // If key is found
    else if (p->key == k) {
        // And it has both children
        if (p->left && p->right) {
            Node *q = findMin(p->right);
            p->key = q->key;
            p->data = q->data;
            remove(p->right, q->key);
        }
        else if (p->right) {
            // Copy right child to p and delete p
            p->key = p->right->key;
            p->data = p->right->data;
            remove(p->right, p->right->key);
        }
        // If it only has left child
        else if (p->left) {
            // Copy left child to p and delete p
            p->key = p->left->key;
            p->data = p->left->data;
            remove(p->left, p->left->key);
        }
        else {
            if (p == p->parent->left) 
                p->parent->left = nullptr;
            else if (p == p->parent->right) 
                p->parent->right = nullptr;
            else
                p = nullptr;
            delete p;
        }
    }
}
```